# "the 3.2 kilometers stretch" or "the 3.2-kilometer stretch"

Tags: nouns, hyphens

> History  enthusiasts  can  bask  in  historical  enclaves scattered  throughout  the  island  while  beach  lovers  can  relax  and  enjoy  sea  sports  along  the  3.2 kilometres stretch of Siloso, Central and Tanjong Beaches.

This sentence is from an article about "Travel in Southeast Asia". The phrase "the 3.2 kilometres stretch of Siloso" is a question to me. I think it should be 
"the 3.2- kilometer stretch of Siloso" as I have learn that"
When Noun + noun is used in measurements, with a number before the first noun,the number is usually joined to the first noun by a hyphen (-)."

Please give me some advice on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When it's part of an "attributive adjective" usage (before the noun) as in ***a three-mile run*** we usually specify the *unit of measurement* in the singular form. And if there's an *integer* (whole number) value before it, we usually link that to the unit with a hyphen, but we don't normally do that with decimal / fractional values, because it makes the whole orthography look clumsy and confusing.